# How to run the iphone youtube clips?

Tags: iphone, youtube

How do really Iphone run youtube clip, which I know there's no support .Flv or flash? Convert on the clip to run them? If so what format they convert it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are H.264 files, encoded by Youtube specially.